# Can a verical laptop stand damage the laptop?

Tags: laptop, ergonomics, laptop-stands

I have replaced my desktop workstation with a 17" laptop, and it is ergonomically terrible, the solution was to use an external keyboard and mouse, but still it would stay way below eye level, some people then suggested a vertical laptop stand so i got the cheapo one below.

[image: Laptop support]

[image: Laptop on the support]

I have searched like crazy on the web for some info or reviews to make sure that it will not cause any kind of damage to the laptop like straining the hinges or any other component by standing in that position, and i could not find anything.

Does anyone here have any kind of experience with this kind of support?Can it cause any damage to the laptop?

The laptop will stay on the support 24/7 and with the lid opened pretty much 8-12 hours a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see any reason why this would damage the screen or lid. The lid is designed to stay open in any position. Mounted as you show it most of the weight of the lid is carried vertically on the hinges.

You should be careful not to block the fan vents if you have them. That will lead to overheating.

Hard drives can generally be mounted in any orientation. This [site](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/212778-32-hard-drive-orientation) discusses hard drive mounting. The consensus is the orientation doesn't matter.

So I can't see this causing any problems.

Comment: It does seem to be the consensus that it will not cause any damage to the laptop, it helped to put my mind at ease,thanks for your input Wayne.

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself constantly using your laptop as your desktop computer (i.e. full time workstation) then you really should consider at the least an external monitor and keyboard / mouse. At best you would get a dedicated desktop computer.

I don't believe that that stand would cause any sort of strain on the computer. In fact keeping it elevated will probably help keep it cooler, increasing the longevity.

Comment: I will definitely consider your sugestions, thank you for your input Josh.

Comment: @OldJim: I missed the fact that you said you had replaced your desktop with this laptop. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: Yes i started working in two different offices, i had virtual machines on a external drive and two desktops for awhile but switching to a laptop was a much better solution.